# getting partial deserialized json when I have extra character causing exception at end of file

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize Json files that can have any number of field. Sometimes I have extra character at the end of the file (extra <,> extra <}> etc. I want to deserialize the rest of the file while skipping the error.

The files can have or have not some field and each field can have subfield. I know the field I'm searching for to check if the file has it.

If the file is properly written I can deserialise it with no problem. I know that Json.net can handle error and output something according to their example.

> I have tried regex to remove the end-of-file character that cause problem but I cant manage to figure all possibility.
>
> I have tried to implement a JsonSerialiserSettings that handle error, but I still only get a null Jobject

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsontext = (
                "{\"name\":\"a Name\", \"parents\":{\"father\":1, \"mother\":0,}, }");

            JObject parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsontext) as JObject;
            Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}", parsed["name"].Value<string>());
            Console.ReadLine();

            string jsontextError = (
                "{\"name\":\"a Name\", \"parents\":{\"father\":1, \"mother\":0,},, }");

            JObject parsederror = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsontextError, new JsonSerializerSettings { Error = HandleDeserializationError }) as JObject;
            if (parsederror == null)
                Console.WriteLine("null parse");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}", parsederror["name"].Value<string>());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static public void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs errorArgs)
        {
            var currentError = errorArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
            errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

I would like parsederror to return something, rather than null.

Comment: I don't think something like this is possible. If you want to deserialize JSON string, it needs to be valid JSON string. As far as I know, partial deserialization is not possible.

Comment: Partial deserialization is not possible, but JSON is just a string and strings can be cleaned. The unfortunate scenario here is that OP doesn't know what these random characters may end up being. So the first approach would be to try to fix this JSON. If you have control over the source of the JSON then fix it. If not, maybe try to find another API that does the same thing but without making such simple mistakes. I'm not sure I would trust the data from an API that cant even output proper JSON.

Comment: [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) this seem to show that some form of error handling is possible I though. As for the files, I'm trying to edit files used by another program, which is why I can't really control the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't assume that your input is well-formed JSON, you've already lost. If you're only considering technical solutions, proceed with caution.

Your problem isn't well-defined. You keep mentioning extra end-of-file stuff, but your example clearly shows extra in-the-middle-of-the-file stuff. If you want any hope of solving this problem in a technical manner, you need to specify *exactly* how the input might have mutated from a valid JSON stream.

If you really *only* need to deal with extra characters beyond the end of a valid, complete JSON stream, the default serializer *appears* to work fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"name\":\"a Name\", \"parents\":{\"father\":1, \"mother\":0}},,,,Look at me! Stuff at the end!";
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
        {
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                dynamic value = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
                Console.WriteLine(value.parents.father); // prints 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to deal with possibly extra stuff in the middle of the file too, then there's not a whole lot you can do without an exact specification of what cases you need to handle. Whatever else you try will likely be a horrific, brittle hack.

Like this one:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"name\":\"a Name\", \"parents\":{\"father\":1, \"mother\":0,},,}";
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
        {
            using (var jsonReader = new SkipErrorsReader(stringReader))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                dynamic value = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
                Console.WriteLine(value.parents.father); // prints 1
            }
        }
    }
}

class SkipErrorsReader : JsonTextReader
{
    private static FieldInfo _charPosFieldInfo = typeof(JsonTextReader)
        .GetField("_charPos", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public SkipErrorsReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader)
    { }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        bool? result;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                result = base.Read();
            }
            catch
            {
                result = null;
                IncrementCharPos();
            }
        } while (result == null);
        return result.Value;
    }

    private void IncrementCharPos()
    {
        int charPos = (int)_charPosFieldInfo.GetValue(this);
        _charPosFieldInfo.SetValue(this, charPos + 1);
    }
}
```

The idea is that it'll 'test' the `Read` operation of the next token in the text stream; if it fails, advance the character position by one and keep trying again until you can consume something successfully.

This will of course skip over any syntax errors originating in *expected* tokens, which could be a bad thing. This also depends on an internal implementation detail of `JsonTextReader`, which is a very bad thing.

Don't use this code. It will only bring misery. Use your time and energy to apply whatever social pressure is necessary to get valid JSON from the other program you say you have no control over.

Comment: There really is only stuff at the end of file, never in the middle. They are Json config fed to a program that are handmade and some people got lazy at the end. The program can read them fine but i wanted to edit them as a practice of json.net use. I will try your first option this evening, if your example work it would be the exact solution i was looking for.

Comment: It worked, Solution 1 was exactly what was needed. Eveything work exactly as I wante it. I can even cast the dynamic object to JObject to get the same behavior I had with the JSon convert result. I can also use JSonSerializer.create() instead of new to use a custom JsonSerializerSetting.